# how can you explain me this?

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop, range, is-empty

It gives me an  empty list if I didnt put x=list(range(a, b, -1)) again in the loop while, why ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please add code as text to the question, not a screenshot

Comment: Please edit your question to contain actual code, not images of code. [This meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) explains many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `a < b` then the range will be created as an empty range. The range won't magically update when `a` and `b` gain new values because the values have already been assigned to the range. That's why you have to recreate the range with the updated values of `a` and `b`.